# logstash configuration with variable index name for elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a logstash config which gets the data from redis and outputs the data to elasticsearch. This is what my configuration file looks like:

```
input {
    redis {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        codec => "json"
        key => "logstash"
        data_type => "list"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        user => "user"
        password => "password"
        host => "host:9200"
        index => "index-%{foo}"
        document_id => "id-%{bar}"
        document_type => "my_type"
        cluster => "my_cluster"
    }
}
```

My elasticsearch instance is proxied on port 9200 by nginx, in reality it runs on a different port. Also the **auth is set using nginx, not shield**. The problem is that when I run a `configtest` on this config, it shows `Configuration OK`. But when I run this script then this error is thrown:

```
Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", 
:backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-
2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:88:in `config_init'", 
"org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:72:in `config_init'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:79:in `initialize'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:74:in `register'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", 
"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", 
"/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-
java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
```

Why is this error thrown? What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Note that I've also tried using

```
host => "http://user:password@host:9200"
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Logstash version 2+, it's not `host` but `hosts`.

Cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts)

> hosts
>   Value type is array
>   Default value is ["127.0.0.1"]
>   Sets the host(s) of the remote instance.

Comment: That works. One question though, if it is mentioned in the documentation, then why did configtest showed `Configuration OK`?

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal it's a guess, but I think configtest only checks if the configuration syntax is correct, but not the configuration options of the filters/outputs/inputs